# Using global variables in servlet evil?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications

I have a `global variable` called `loginAttempt` in a `servlet class`. What will happen to this `global variable` if two `requests` hit on the same time?What will happen is an unforeseeable event.

Is having global variables in servlet an evil ??

If i put the `loginAttempt` is side `doPost()` its initializing each time.

Comment: Isn't that what the different levels of contexts are for? Sorry, haven't worked with servlets a long time now. Just an idea.

Comment: store it in the session, any other place it will be shared by all the other users

Comment: @fmodos you mean that value shared to all the requests accessing by different users??

Comment: Instead of a global variable, maybe you should consider a singleton?

Comment: yes, it will be shared

Comment: @fge is singleton instance not shared across the application ? Please elaborate.Sorry,Did'nt get it.

Comment: Forget the singleton; use what @fmodos tells you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

1. Your variable is readable/writeable by any other class. You have no control to ensure that they all do sensible things with it. One of them could overwrite it/incorrectly increment it, etc
2. The is one instance of a servlet, per JVM. So may threads may try to access it concurrently. Because it is global, and you are not providing any synchronization/access control, it will not be thread-safe. Also, if you ever run the servlet in some kind of cluster with different JVMs, then the variable will not be shared between them and you will have multiple loginAttempt variables.

If you *have* to have it in the servlet, make it static but do not make it public. Provide getters/setters to access and update it. Learn about thread-safe programming so that multiple-threads can update it and read it safely.

Much better, store it in the servlet-context. This should be where you store servlet-wide data like this.

Answer (score 2):

They are not evil as long as you understand that there is generally only a single instance of a servlet created and the global variable will be shared by all clients of that servlet - that is every request, on different threads at the same time and by multiple users at the same time.

I am guessing that your global variable `loginAttempt` is counting the number of login attempts then as long as this is done in a thread safe way it would be a reasonable way of counting the number of login attempts made on this servlet. This would be for all users though. If you want login attempts per user then you probably need to create a session and use the session context to store this sort of info.

Answer (score 1):

In a large number of concurrent access,You may want to pay attention to the thread safety problem of Servlet...and you can try the following methods to avoid this problem...

1、

```
public class loginAttempt extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel {
...
}
```

2、
The second method：
Use the `synchronized` keyword

3、
Avoid the use of global variable

Comment: Using `synchronized` in Servlets is a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a session attribute. Otherwise the global variable concept will screw you up totally. 
Using session is a good idea as it's
 1) If the web service is restarted, the session data is not lost

2) In a load balanced environment, the session data is stored in a central location, meaning any server can serve the request and have access to the session data.

So it's accessible yet it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

YES.
Global variables are shared with everyone

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if your variable is read-only, it should be fine. But in most cases, global variables are evil. I can't give you a solution because I don't have your code but I am sure there is an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

In your usecase, it is beyond evil. loginAttempt will be shared by all threads accessing the servlet

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no terminology called `global variable` in Java. They are called class variable or instance variable.

Second, Yes its bad practice to have instance variable in the Servlet if you are assigning   request or session scoped data as it will be shared by all threads.

You can use it for application-wide values, most often obtained from context parameters. or If the data never changes (immutable) like Constants.